# How do you differentiate an airdrop transaction from a normal transaction in the etherscan API?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, smartcontracts, etherscan, airdrop

How do you differentiate an airdrop transaction from a normal transaction in the etherscan API?

I want to know how to differentiate an airdrop transaction from a normal transaction using the etherscan API. I read the documentation of the api, I contacted the support and looked for airdrops but it does not appear on their website

Comment: Can you give examples of airdrop transactions? If the airdrop is performed with a specific function, you'll be able to differentiate it from a regular token transfer between wallets. But it all depends on the context. Some airdrops might not be differentiable from regular token transfers.

Comment: I mean any airdrop in general

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to perform an airdrop. Some of which are not distinguishable from swaps and other types of transfer.

Some mint new tokens, some transfer tokens from a vault address. Some airdops are initiated by an authorized address, some have users to claim their tokens.

So generally, there is no generic way to recognize an airdrop.